# Inserting a number in the middle of a vector

Tags: c, vector

I made this code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    int n, i, v[1000];
    printf("Type the size of the vector: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Type a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf ("%d ", v[i]);
    }
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

It is working, but what I need to do now is to put another number right in the middle of this vector. So if you put 4 numbers on it, 1, 2, 3 and 4 for example, I need to make it possible to put another number in the middle, so it would be 1, 2, **9**, 3 and 4 for example. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: 1) Find the middle; 2) shift the elements past that point to the right; 3) insert your new element at the newly vacant place

Comment: Mid insertion requires you "make a hole" by pushing the content at the current location you want to fill "forward" one item in the collection. Since this will, by definition, use overlapped memory, consider `memmove()` (*not* `memcpy()`) to do this.

Comment: Please try to give your questions titles that describe the problem better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int k;

k = n / 2;

for (i = n; i > k; --i)
   v[i] = v[i - 1];
v[k] = insertionValue;
```

Comment: that could be better achieved with memmove(). Depending on the machine, the blitting with memmove() could be optimized by hardware.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was exactly what I was looking for.
And I won't forget about giving my questions better titles (:

Answer (score 0):

You have to realloc your vector, shift all value after the middle 1 to right, then assign the value you want to the middle.

Comment: Read the question ... the array wasn't malloced, so it can't be realloced.